# Detect window size onload as well as upon resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, resize

I have a script in place that adjusts the height of a div whenever the window is resized, and it works great. How do I keep this functionality, but also set the size initially when the page is loaded?

Currently, the window had to be manually resized before the height is defined.

```
$(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);
function resizeWindow( e ) {
var newWindowHeight = $(window).height()-207;
$("#sponsorscroll").css("height", newWindowHeight );
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `load` to your events to listen for

```
$(window).on("resize load", resizeWindow);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and so obvious! Thank you for saving me a ridiculous amount of time... :)

Comment: Thanks for this Zoltan, this also helped me out with some projects.